Unexpected Stage Skipping Behavior in YAML Pipelines Triggered Using Azure DevOps SDK
We have a YAML release pipeline with multiple stages with below dependencies defined:
Example:
Stage: A

Stage: B

Stage: C
DependsOn:
- A 
- B

Stage: D

Stage: E

Stage: F
DependsOn:
 - D
 - E

Issue:
I'm trying to trigger this YAML release from .NET tool which uses the Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi from Azure DevOps SDK.
public int RunYamlPipeline(RunPipelineParameters runParam, int pipelineId)
{     
  VssConnection vssConnection = GetVssConnection();     
  PipelinesHttpClient pipelinesHttpClient = vssConnection.GetClient<PipelinesHttpClient>(Guid.NewGuid());    
  runParam.PreviewRun = false;   
  var result = pipelinesHttpClient.RunPipelineAsync(runParam, TfsSettings.TfsProjectName, pipelineId).Result     
  return result.Id;
}

In RunPipelineParameters, we are passing the StagesToSkip.
When I'm triggering the pipeline from this method with provided StagesToSkip as "StageA, Stage D", observed that in the pipeline run, Stage C got skipped whereas Stage F ran to successful completion.
When triggered the same pipeline from Azure DevOps UI & unselected/skipped the stages as above, both stages C and F ran successfully.
Could someone pls help me understand why Stage C was skipped and Stage F ran when the pipeline was triggered from the tool?

I am unable to reproduce the issue. When I add "A" and "D" to "StagesToSkip" in the code, stages A and D are skipped and the remaining stages run successfully, which is the same result as the Azure DevOps UI deselecting/skipping stages "A" and "D".
My YAML :
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: 

- stage: B
  jobs:
  - job: 

- stage: C
  dependsOn:
  - A 
  - B
  jobs:
  - job: 
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello C
- stage: D
  jobs:
  - job: 

- stage: E
  jobs:
  - job: 

- stage: F
  dependsOn:
  - D 
  - E
  jobs:
  - job: 
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello F

My code in a simple console program:
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {          
            // Define pipeline parameters
            RunPipelineParameters runParam = new RunPipelineParameters();
            runParam.StagesToSkip.Add("A");
            runParam.StagesToSkip.Add("D");

            int pipelineId = 140; // replace with your pipeline ID

            // Run the YAML pipeline
            int resultId = RunYamlPipeline(runParam, pipelineId);
            Console.WriteLine($"Pipeline run ID: {resultId}");
        }

        public static int RunYamlPipeline(RunPipelineParameters runParam, int pipelineId)
        {
            Uri orgUrl = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/orgname");
            string pat = "";

            // Create a connection
            VssConnection vssConnection = new VssConnection(orgUrl, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, pat));

            PipelinesHttpClient pipelinesHttpClient = vssConnection.GetClient<PipelinesHttpClient>();
            runParam.PreviewRun = false;
            var result = pipelinesHttpClient.RunPipelineAsync(runParam, "projectname", pipelineId).Result;
            return result.Id;
        }

    }
}


Test result:

When chooses to skip stage "A" and "D" in the Azure DevOps UI:

Please double check if you have passed the stage to skip value correctly in your code.
